# Saving/Restoring view state for fragment replace transaction

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm doing a replace transaction from FragmentA to FragmentB and adding it to back stack. Therefore, the life cycle events will be fired like so:

> FragmentB: onAttach -> onCreate 
>   then FragmentA: onPause -> onStop -> onDestroyView

When I press back to go back from B to A the life cycle events will fire like so:

> B: onPause -> onStop -> onDestroyView -> onDestroy -> onDetach 
>   then A: onCreateView -> onStart -> onResume

I'm trying to save and restore what the users sees in FragmentA when coming back to it. FragmentA is just a RecyclerView so I want FragmentA to have the same items and scrollPosition as when the user left it when coming back. I'm trying to make it look as if it was just an Activity pop in pop out.

I'm trying to utilize the RecyclerView's layoutManager state. Saving it in FragmentA's onSaveInstanceState and restoring it in FragmentA's onCreateView or onRestoreInstanceState. However, it doesn't work because FragmentA's onSaveInstanceState is never called throughout the entire flow.

I've considered other options but these are not available to me due to constraints out of my control:

- Can't make another activity for FragmentB and do an activity navigation transaction instead
- Can't use an add fragment transaction instead

Comment: Hi, on the latest support library, the fragments will be restored automatically as long as you don't try to recreate them. Have tested your scenario with a dummy list. scroll position and items remains same.

Comment: What do you mean "restored automatically"? `onSaveInstanceState` is never called. `savedInstanceState` of `onCreateView` is always null, `getView()` called in `onCreateView()` when returning from backstack is also always null. I'm not sure what version of the support library you are on but I'm not at liberty to change the version I'm working with.